# Change img src when any image in a div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have a `div` containing images below and

```
<div class="div1">
    <img src="images/pic1.png">
    <img src="images/pic2.png">
    <img src="images/pic3.png">
</div>
```

when I click on any image, the image path should be changed to `images/pic1-h.png`

Here's what I've tried in jQuery, but it's not working

```
$(".div1").click(function(){
    var r1 = $("img").attr("src").replace(".", ".-h");
    $('img').attr("src", r1);
});
```

Comment: The issue here is that you are capturing three instances of `image` and all of them have different values at src.

Answer (score 2):

Your `img` selector, is returning every image on the page, not the one which was clicked on.

Try this:

```
$(".div1 img").click(function() {
    var r1 = $(this).attr("src").replace(".", "-h.");
    $(this).attr("src", r1);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nsTUn/)

**EDIT**

OP redefined question to 'click on parent and all images should change':

```
$(".div1").click(function() {
    $("IMG", $(this)).each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace(".", "-h.");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
});
```

**[New Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsTUn/1/)**

Comment: And the replace will return nothing.

Comment: When i click on any images in that div, the all images src in that div should be changed

Comment: Not working, only one image src is changed but not all at once.

Comment: Could you post the code you have in your OP. The code does work, as evidenced by the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".div1 img").click(function(){    
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace('.','-h.'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the order of your parameters in replace -- it should be

```
replace(".","-h.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".div1 img").click(function(){
    var r1 = $(this).attr("src").replace(".","-h.")
    $(this).attr("src", r1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".div1").click(function(){
    var $img = $('img', this);
    var r1 = $img.attr("src").replace(".", "-h.");
    $img.attr("src", r1);
});
```

You are out of luck when the file is called `help.me.png`